# Can Google play console Alpha testing have two different apks for two different groups?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have apk1 ( Older closed alpha testers ) & apk2 ( Latest &  Want different alpha testers closed group )

We have one set of functionality in apk2 that has to be tested separately than the one which is under current alpha testers closed group i.e. apk1.

Can I release the new apk2 under alpha closed testers group with the first group of testers having access to apk1?

Beta testing is no longer closed it's open hence it's out from options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Since Google I/O this year Google Play introduced the ability to have multiple closed testing tracks. See [this help article for all the details](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213).

Just create multiple closed tests, one for the old alpha testers, and one for the new alpha testers.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The users on the new track, can't see the newly released apk. I've removed them from the previous track too. I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the app, and it picks up the old one.